# metro bundler has encountered an internal error and hangs in terminal never loading

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo

I am using explo-cli to develop a react native project. My project was compiling just fine yesterday and today I open it up for it to tell me that it can't find module './iter-step'. Prior to the can't find module './iter-step' it told me it couldn't find 'babel-runtime'. To fix both issues I just ran 'npm install --save [missing package name] and it seemed to work and both times it brought me back to this current error that I'm posting about.

"metro bundler has encountered an internal error, please check your terminal error output for more details"

```
[15:12:06] undefined
[15:12:06] Failed building JavaScript bundle.
Building JavaScript bundle [===============================================] 99
```

I never explicitly imported 'babel-runtime' or 'core-js' so it feels random for my project to complain that they're missing. Maybe a vscode extension I have placed them somewhere in my code without my knowledge. Anyone ever have this issue?

This is my new package.json.

```
{
  "name": "empty-project-template",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.3",
    "expo": "^30.0.1",
    "firebase": "^5.8.0",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "number-is-nan": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.21.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.3",
    "styled-icons": "^6.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try just delete npm_modules directory and run `npm install`?

Comment: That worked! I feel super silly for not thinking of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the node_modules directory and running `npm install` again did the trick like Talgat suggested.

Comment: Well, it helps me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Will have to delete the node_modules folder and then do an npm install command, I think it will work